# Как отсортировать входные данные

Tags: python, python-3.x

Входные данные:

```
4

200 50
203 50
202 50
300 65
```

На выходе должно получится

```
300 65
200 50
202 50
203 50
```

Мой ответ

```
300 65
200 50
203 50
202 50
```

Итог я смог сделать сортировку по баллам но как сделать по номеру?

```
def M(m): 
  for b in m:  
    print (*b) 
N = int(input())
if N >=1 and N <= 1000:
  NM = []
  for i in range(N):
    NM.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
NM.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
M(NM)
def M(m): 
  for b in m:  
    print(*b)
```

Comment: Что из данных номер, а что баллы?

Comment: 300 номер 50 баллы

Comment: И для одинаковых баллов сортировка идет по возрастанию по номеру?

Comment: да все верно ..

Comment: пытался sorted применить но чет ни то

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас у вас сортируется только по второму элементу, т.е. по баллам, а номер никак не учитывается.

Нужно добавить номеру в ключ вторым элементом в кортеж, так при равных баллах, сортировка будет делаться по номеру. Чтоб это делалось в порядке возрастания, нужно номер добавлять со знаком минус, так как для сортировки по баллам по убыванию используется `reverse=True`:

```
...
NM.sort(key = lambda x: (x[1], -x[0]), reverse=True)
...
```